# Testing a batch class where I need to modify System fields?

Tags: apex, soql, batch

I have a batch class that should update accounts based on `CreatedDate` and `LastModifiedDate` so I turned to this guide: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000332070&type=1

However, I can't seem to find the record with a soql query inside my test class

```
String accountJSON = '{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v25.0/sobjects/Account/0013M00001AikcgQAB"},"Id":"0013M00001AikcgQAB","Name":"Test","Inactive__c":"true","CreatedDate":"2012-10-04T17:54:26.000+0000","LastModifiedDate":"2019-10-04T17:54:26.000+0000"}'; 

Account acc = (Account) JSON.deserialize(accountJSON, Account.class);
// System.debug(acc) returns the result with my dummy Id and custom date fields, but I can't do much else with it
List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account]; // returns an empty array, ()
```

Is it possible to somehow get this Account record with its specific createddate / lastmodifieddate?

Answer (score 1):

If you [Enable the 'Create Audit Fields' permission](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000334139&type=1), make sure your user has this permission assigned (perhaps by Permission Set), then perform an insert DML operation, you can set the dates as you desire.

```
String accountJSON = '{"attributes":{"type":"Account"},"Name":"Test","Inactive__c":"true","CreatedDate":"2012-10-04T17:54:26.000+0000","LastModifiedDate":"2019-10-04T17:54:26.000+0000"}'; 

Account acc = (Account) JSON.deserialize(accountJSON, Account.class);
insert acc;
List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];
```

Notice how I had to remove the Id field, though. This is because of the [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm). You can't access most types of records in production in a unit test. This prevents accidental addition/loss/modification of data. Further, the audit fields permission only allows setting audit fields on insert, not on update.

When possible, you should try and write your code such that it is not time-dependent in this manner, though.

Comment: I do need the Id fields though because I need to create tasks related to the account as well. The batch class itself is about closing and masking records if they haven't been touched for X amount of time - it's GDPR related. Not sure if there is another way of testing.

Regarding your comment above: `insert acc` overwrites `LastModifiedDate` and `DateCreated` so that won't work unfortunately

Comment: @erikvm It worked when I tested it. Regardless, this is an apparent [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You need to ask about how to test your code (X), not how to manipulate the audit fields (Y). You likely need a Dependency Injection technique or something, but I can't give you a specific answer without seeing your code.